# What is the space complexity of Dijkstra Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

As per my understanding. The space complexity will be O(V). An array of V nodes will be created which in turn  be used to create the Min heap.

But [this](http://igraph.wikidot.com/algorithm-space-time-complexity) link is stating that It is O(V^2)? I don't understand how it can be O(V^2)?

I have search the same topic in the Book entitled [Introduction_to_Algorithms by  Thomas H. Cormen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)  but still not able to find the answer. 
I Don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm can be implemented in many different ways, leading to resource usage. The page you link gives the resource usage the implementations in the specific library being described.

I can't think of a way of implementing Dijkstra to use $|V|^2$ space, but I would note two things.

1. $O(\cdot)$ only gives an upper bound. Even if the implementation actually uses space $O(|V|)$, it's not *wrong* to say that it uses $O(|V|^2)$ or even $O(2^{|V|})$, just as it's not wrong to say that I earn less than a billion dollars a year. However, it would be unusual to say $O(|V|^2)$ if it was easy to prove the stronger bound of $O(|V|)$ (I also earn less than a million dollars a year), and it *is* easy to prove $O(|V|)$ for most implementations of Dijkstra.
2. The page quotes the running time as $O(s|E|\log|E|+V)$, where $s$ is the number of sources being considered. It's easy to imagine space usage of $O(s|V|)$ so maybe they wrote $O(|V|^2)$ since $s\leq|V|$.  But that would also be strange, given that the quoted running time shows they're not afraid to use $s$.